# Adding a empty XMLAttribute in a XMLElement on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I need to create an XML file with some elements that have some attributes, some of which are null. I just want to let the null attributes be visible in the XML file.

An example query is:

```
 SELECT XMLElement("PropertySet",
                  XMLATTRIBUTES('TEST' AS "OrderId",
                                    '' AS "DHLCode") FROM DUAL AS RESULT
```

Which produces:

```
<PropertySet OrderId= "TEST" > <\PropertySet>
```

But I need something like

```
<PropertySet OrderId= "TEST"  DHLCode = "" ><\PropertySet>
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Are you sure about what the statement produces? This should rather be something like `<PropertySet OrderId="TEST"/>` In XML - normally - it is perfectly OK to ommit empty elements or attributs. This is more or less left to the using/reading code...

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping them in the same XMLATTRIBUTES

```
SELECT XMLElement("PropertySet",
                    XMLATTRIBUTES(
                    'TEST' AS "OrderId", 
                    '' AS "DHLCode"
                    )
                 )
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: The correct query should be `SELECT XMLElement("PropertySet",
     XMLATTRIBUTES('TEST' AS "OrderId", 
     '' AS "DHLCode")
    )FROM DUAL;`